# C string truncated bug

Tags: c, string, yacc

i'm working on a school subject about syntax analysis. The goal is to create a small language in order to create vector graphics with the cairo library. We choosed to use an intermediaire state in C.

We use Yacc to generate a C code which is compiled by gcc. It works fine but i have some problem with strings.

Here is the code is use :

```
        int sumChar = 0 ;

        char outnb1[20];
        char outnb2[20];

        sprintf(outnb1, "%f;", $4);
        sprintf(outnb2, "%f;", $8);

        sumChar = (6+strlen($2)+1+5+strlen($2)+1+strlen(outnb1)+strlen($6)+strlen($7)+strlen(outnb2)+strlen($10)+strlen($11)+1+1+strlen($14)+1);

// $ 14 is the string returned by another part of the code.

        printf("String = %s\nSIZE = %d\n",$14,strlen($14));

//The printf here is exact and the string is not truncated :
//cairo_line_to ( cr ,prevPoint[0] ,prevPoint[1]);
//cairo_move_to ( cr ,prevPoint[0] ,prevPoint[1]);

        char *result = malloc(sizeof(char)*sumChar);
        sprintf(result, "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s","\n\nint ",$2,";","\nfor(",$2,"=",outnb1,$6,$7,outnb2,$10,$11,")","{",$14,"}");
        printf("String after sprintf = %s\nSIZE = %d\n",$14,strlen($14));

//The printf print something like :
//cairo_line_to ( cr ,prevPoint[0] ,prevPoint[1]);
//cairo_move_to ( cr ,prevPoint[0]�

        $$ = result;
```

I don't really understand why the string is truncated after the malloc. It's obviously a memory bug but i don't know why. Any ideas or solutions ?

EDIT :

Yacc rule:

```
%union
{
    double number;
    char * str;
};

%token DRAW <number>NB <str>COMP <str>VARNAME <str>VARFOR <str>INC;
%type <str>D;
%type <str>BLOCFOR;
%type <str>FOR;

FOR : '(' VARFOR '=' NB ';' VARFOR COMP NB ';' VARFOR INC ')' '{' BLOCFOR '}' 
    {
        int sumChar = 0 ;
        char outnb1[20];
        char outnb2[20];
        sprintf(outnb1, "%f;", $4);
        sprintf(outnb2, "%f;", $8);
        sumChar += (6+strlen($2)+1+5+strlen($2)+1+strlen(outnb1)+strlen($6)+strlen($7)+strlen(outnb2)+strlen($10)+strlen($11)+1+1+strlen($14)+1);
        printf("VALUE OF BLOCFOR = %s\nSIZE = %d\n",$14,strlen($14));

        char *result = malloc(sizeof(char)*(sumChar+1));
        sprintf(result, "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s","\n\nint ",$2,";","\nfor(",$2,"=",outnb1,$6,$7,outnb2,$10,$11,")","{",$14,"}");
        printf("VALUE OF BLOCFOR AFTER RESULT = %s\nSIZE = %d\n",$14,strlen($14));
        printf("%s\n",result );
        $$ = result;
    }

BLOCFOR : DRAW D '$' {$$ = $2; printf("INSIDE BLOCFOR %s\nSIZE = %d\n",$2,strlen($2));}
```

I hope it help. I can't really give a working code because it would need a simplified lex file. Howewer i can say that with :

```
char result[sumChar];
```

`result` is correct but the `$$ = result` don't work ( i can't use the value returned with FOR it's just random char like �G�+0��I�F���I�)

Here is the parsing and the return of str value in the lex source :

```
<FOR>[[:alpha:]]+ {yylval.str = strdup(yytext);return VARFOR;}
```

SOLVED : Problem solved, it was a bad calculation of sumChar and allocation inside the D token.

Comment: Is `result` `NULL`? Are you sure that you allocating enough memory?

Comment: `result` isn't `NULL` if I allocate more memory (something like 100*sizeof(char)) i just get this 

`cairo_line_to ( cr ,prevPoint[0] ,prevPoint[1]);
cairo_move_to ( cr ,prevPoint[0]1`

Comment: Can you please provide the complete Yacc rule? And also tell us how you parse and pass the token values? And if you could provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that would be super. And please do not add any of this as comments, but edit your question instead.

Comment: I just edited the first post with more complete example

Answer (score 0):

The variable `sumChar` doesn't contain an extra `+1` for the terminating `'\0'` character. This will most likely end up causing *undefined behavior*, of which your problem could be a symptom of. Either add it to `sumChar` or to the `malloc` call.